# socket.io-redis not forwarding messages to sockets on a namespace

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a solution where an application is emitting messages using socket.io-emitter and a socket server is handling the messages.

The socket server receives messages from the client browser without an issue however it does not pickup any messages from the other application which are sent over the redis adapter.

I've debugged the redis adapter and can see that the messages are being received and I can also see that they are associated with the correct namespace. They just appear to not be firing the socket.on() event

The server code has more going on however basically boils down to the following

```
io.adapter(redisIO({host: redisHost, port: redisPort}));     
io.of('/mynamespace').on('connection',
    function(socket) {
       // This message never gets fired
       socket.on('other-server-message',dosomething);
       // This message works fine
       socket.on('message-from-browser-client',dosomethingelse);
    }
);
```

There isn't much documentation around so any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

I eventually realised what the issue was. I was misunderstanding what the socket.io-emitter was doing.

I was sending a message from the emitter and then trying to capture it on the server and then push it out to the clients. The emitter is actually broadcasting directly to the clients in the web browser as if it was just another server socket (which is what I wanted).

Soon as i updated the client code to check for the message it worked perfectly